# Where can I find a threaded tub overflow trim plate?

Tags: bathroom, drain

Replacing all the tub trim including the overflow plate and drain trim. I cannot find an overflow plate like this that goes onto a threaded pipe without any screws.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Look up "Watco Innovator Snap-On Bathtub Overflow Plate Kit"

Comment: @cutrightjm, please provide a proper answer so this question can be resolved.